# How to get a specific state with all resolved value with name of state in AngularJS UI router?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing, angular-ui-router

How to get a specific state with all resolved data with name of state in AngularJS UI router (it is not in a controller)?

For example:

```
$state.get('a name')
```

should get me specific state but if this state has a resolve value how can I access to this value? Or get it? All resolve values are like functions.

Answer (score 0):

you can deal with `$state.$current` - and it's `resolve` property. or if you are passing data in `view` there is `view['yourViewName'].data`

```
  {
    data: undefined
    includes: Object
    locals: extend
    navigable: extend
    ownParams: extend
    params: extend
    parent: extend
    path: Array[3]
    resolve: Object
    self: Object
    toString: ()
    url: UrlMatcher
    views: Object
  }
```